# Connected App running user

Tags: rest-api, user, connected-apps, system-admin

I've created a connected app for integration usage and I put a specific Sys Admin running user for this - But when data is sent via the Web Service that the integration created - Its still put me (my own user) as the owner of the records.
I want that the owner will be the one who defined to be the running user for the App.

any Idea? Or some clarification about this subject?
Thanks..
[image]

Comment: Are you invoking the web service from your own user in salesforce?

Comment: I'm invoking it from postMan - Access with token directly to the Connected app

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only A Single class the "Apex Plugin Class", runs in the context of the specified user.

From Salesforce Docs:

> For Run As, select the name of the user to run the plug-in as. The
>   plug-in runs on behalf of a user account. If the user isn’t authorized
>   for the connected app, use the authorize method to do so.

As you are not using that feature, your logic will run in the context of the user whose access token you have provided via postman.

Src: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/connected_app_create.htm

Comment: Thank you. This is still on Tests environment - on the high environments, I will create the token with the user I wish to see as the owner, instead of using this feature... Is that will work?
@pranay jaiswal